# MSM & Super Search results howto retrieve site info for each result

Tags: solspace, multi-site-manager

We're using MSM with Solspace Super Search, each sub site is reached through a subdomain, eg:

site_1.oursite.com

site_2.outsite.com

But, on a search results page that displays results from across all sites, all of the path tags I have tried, such as 'auto_path', get resolved to the current sub domain for all results, and not to the site for each entry.

I could group the results according to sub domain and then set the paths, but is there a way to get the full path for each entry without doing this?

```
    {exp:super_search:results paginate="bottom" limit="40"}
        <?php $class = {count} % 2 == 0?'even':'odd';?>
        <tr>
        <td class="<?=$class?>" width="30%" valign="top"><b><a href="{url_title_path='/article'}">{title}</a></b></td>
        <td class="<?=$class?>" width="10%" valign="top">{author}</td>
        <td class="<?=$class?>" width="10%" valign="top">{entry_date format="%d/%m/%y"}</td>
        </tr>

        {paginate}
                <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
        {/paginate}

    {/exp:super_search:results}
```

Comment: Can you show what your template code looks like? :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I've updated the question with the loop code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of EE and Super Search are you using? I tested this with each of these variables and they worked perfectly (of course, each one needs to be configured manually for each channel's preferences in each site):

- {auto_path}
- {comment_auto_path}
- {comment_entry_id_auto_path}
- {comment_url_title_auto_path}

Comment: I had set the results path as a relative path! Thank you.